# ZonedDateTime correctly parses "GMT" zone from pattern 'O' but not "UTC"

Tags: java, java-time, java-17, zoneddatetime, datetimeformatter

The following correctly parses the text input "2022-12-29 01:16:03 GMT+08:00".

```
public ZonedDateTime parseZonedDateTime(String timeStr) {
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss O");

  ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(timeStr, dtf);

  return zonedDateTime;
}
```

However, if the input string is "2022-12-29 01:16:03 UTC-08:00", ZonedDateTime.parse() method throws

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-12-29 01:16:03 UTC-08:00' could not be parsed at index 20
```

See this [code run on Java 12 at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/VZrFmi).

According to the DateTimeFormatter doc, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

both "GMT+08:00" and "UTC-08:00" are considered localized zone-offset 'O'.

What should be the correct pattern so that the parser accepts both GMT and UTC inputs?

I have tried using the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss OOOO" but the behavior is the same.

There is a similar question [Why does `GMT+8` fail to parse with pattern `O` despite being copied straight out of doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287103/why-does-gmt8-fail-to-parse-with-pattern-o-despite-being-copied-straight-ou) and according to this, the bug was fixed in Java 9 build b116.

However I'm using java 17.0.4.1-librca

Comment: What Locale are you running this in? Have you tried explicitly specifying `Locale.ROOT`?

Comment: I am using the default Locale. I tried explicitly specifying Locale.ROOT but the issue persists.

Comment: It works for me, no errors. JDK 17.0.3 oracle. Try another JDK, or post full Junit test, there may be something you don''t see.

Comment: @pdem I do not see how you did that. Can you copy and run the code [from Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/VZrFmi)? I cannot get it to run on Java 12 nor Java 19. Or paste your code somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should be the correct pattern so that the parser accepts both GMT
> and UTC inputs?

Use `V` instead of `O` i.e. use the pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV`.

**Demo**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Stream.of(
                "2022-12-29 01:16:03 GMT+08:00",
                "2022-12-29 01:16:03 UTC-08:00"
            )
            .map(s -> ZonedDateTime.parse(s, dtf))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
        ;
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-12-29T01:16:03+08:00[GMT+08:00]
2022-12-29T01:16:03-08:00[UTC-08:00]
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/xD8L9b)</kbd>

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: How about "2022-07-31 23:48:57 UTC-5"? the "VV" pattern fails on "UTC-5" part.

Comment: @LeilJanC - Unfortunately, when it comes to date parsing, there is nothing like *one size fits all*. You can define a `DateTimeFormatter` using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` that can work for this variant as well. Let me know if you need help and I will post an update.

Comment: @LeilJanC I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about using only [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats. And I suggest always expanding an offset to use padding zero, and use both hours and minutes. And not insert `UTC` nor `GMT`. So instead of `UTC-5`, use `-05:00`. While the contraction of hours-only in an offset is allowed under ISO 8601, I have seen multiple libraries not accept such inputs. Best to use expanded format. Example: `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2022-12-29T01:16:03+08:00" )` — easy-peasy.